# Rails 3 saving a record issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-1.9.2

I have been working with Rails 3.0.5 and Ruby 1.9.2 and I have noticed that a new record doesn't get saved or isn't available for use instantly.

For example

```
def create    
    @some_record = Pool.new(params[:pool])  
      @some_record.users.push(current_user)
    if params[:commit] == "Add More"          
      @some_record.save        
      @some_record.do_something
    elsif params[:commit] == "Save"
      do_something_else(params)
    elsif params[:commit] == 'Cancel'
      redirect_to user_url(current_user)
    end    
 redirect_to some_other_url(current_user)
end
```

So when I save the record and call `some_record.do_something` the saved object isn't available instantly. `current_user.some_records` doesn't contain the newly added record but `current_user.some_records.all` displays the newly saved record. However on the console I am able to view the newly created record with `current_user.some_records`.

I'm sure I am missing something fundamental to Rails 3. I have also tried the same with `current_user.some_records.build(params[:some_record]` and I have the same problem. Does Rails 3 save the object instantly or is there some kind of delayed write/save because the same problem does not occur with Rails 3.0.3.

Also I am not using an authentication plugin like authlogic/devise and I simply save the current_user object to the session. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. WOuld appreciate any help?

Its also a many-to-many association between some_record and users

Comment: Sorry Big mistake on my part. The save is called after the push to the association array.

Answer (score 1):

```
current_user.some_records
```

does not contain the newly added record because you did not save the operation after assigning `@some_record.users.push(current_user)`.
All you have to do is to add `.save` after the assignment and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The model structure is not clear from your question but let's assumed that `current_user` `belongs_to` `some_records`
To force a database read try this:

```
current_user.some_records(true)
```

By default `forcereload = false`, to override this you should pass `true`

Comment: I don't understand. You mean a database read is not a default setting and needs to be explicitly called. Whats the advantage/use of such a setting.

Comment: Doesn't development mode reload everything implicitly.

Comment: "If the associated object has already been retrieved from the database for this object, the cached version will be returned" - from here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html